# Content checking some, not all, class attributes

Tags: class, raku, introspection

I have a class with attributes. I want to check whether some but not all are defined. So:

```
class A { 
    has $.a is rw;
    has $.b is rw;
    has $.c is rw;
    has $.d is rw;

    method delete { ... }
}

my A $x .= new(:a<hi>, :d<good>);

## later
$x.b = 'there';

## code in which $x.c may or may not be defined.

## now I want to check if the attributes a, b, and c are defined, without
## needing to know about d
my Bool $taint = False;
for <a b c> {
    $taint &&= $x.$_.defined
}
```

This will cause errors because an object of type A doesn't have a method 'CALL-ME' for type string.

Is there an introspection method that gives me the values of attributes of a class?

`$x.^attributes` gives me their names and types, but not their values.

I think there must be some way since `dd` or `.perl` provide attribute values - I think.

Comment: If all the class's *public* attributes are meant to be read/write, you can apply the [`is rw`](https://docs.raku.org/type/Attribute#index-entry-trait_is_rw_(Attribute)-trait_is_rw) trait to the class.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, it is called `get_value`.  It needs the object of the attribute passed to it.  For example:

```
class A {
    has $.a = 42;
    has $.b = 666;
}
my $a = A.new;
for $a.^attributes -> $attr {
    say "$attr.name(): $attr.get_value($a)"
}
# $!a: 42
# $!b: 666
```

Comment: Thx. Found documentation of get_value in Class Attribute. It violates encapsulation, so should not normally be used.

Comment: Indeed.  But it's good that you actually *can* introspect, without having to resort to using internals that may change. :-)