# How to access the attributes of a class indirectly

Tags: class, attributes, raku

This is similar to, but not quite the same as another of my questions: [Content checking some, not all, class attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59520029/content-checking-some-not-all-class-attributes)

I am writing a test to verify the effect of processing on a object. But I can't work out how to get the value of a known set of the object's attributes but test with the same code. Something like the following (which does not work):

```
class A { has $.a, has $.b, has $.c };
my A $v .=new(:1a, :2b);

for <a b> { ok $v.{$_} > 0 }; # this does not work, but illustrates the intent.
```

If instead of an object I had used a Hash, then it is easy to get values from the Hash knowing the keys.

At the moment all I can think of is to test each attribute:

```
ok $v.a > 0;
ok $v.b > 0;
```

In addition, I don't want to look at ALL the attributes of the object, which is what .^attributes gives me, only some of them.

Comment: You can make your not-working example work quite simply: `for <a b> { ok $v."$_"() > 0 };`. Would that solve your problem? You could also implement the `Associative` role to make your sample work as-is.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue you are encountering – and the reason tests like this are easier with `Hash`es than with `Class`es – is that you are passing in a `Str` when you need to pass in an object.  This issue doesn't come up with `Hashe`s because (by default), `Hash` keys already *are* strings.

The other important thing to remember is that, technically speaking, there *isn't* any way to directly access the attributes of a Raku object from outside of the object – Raku does not have public attributes, just attributes you can access from a public accessor method.  This may seem like a pedantic distinction, but it's important here: it means that you need a callable `Method` object (which is more specific than the "object" I mentioned in the previous paragraph).

As Tyil mentioned in a comment, you can get Raku to dwym with the code `for <a b> { ok $v."$_"() > 0 };`.  The reason this works is that the final `()` forces Raku to treat the interpolated value of `"$_"` as a `Callable`, which in this case means a `Method`.

However, I'd prefer to be slightly more explicit and use the following syntax:

```
for $v.^methods.grep({.name ~~ 'a' | 'b'}) { ok $_($v) > 0}
```

(This takes advantage of the fact that `$object.method` and `method($object)` are syntactically equivalent).

Note that we have the `grep` above because you wanted to test just some of `A`'s methods.  However, even if you want to test all of the methods you added to `A`, you may still need the grep to exclude `BUILDALL`, which is returned by `$v.^methods(:local)`.  I haven't figured out whether that is intentional or a bug (it doesn't *seem* like a local method) and would appreciate anyone's thoughts on that.

Comment: .oO ( Imagine you just met a "object!" protocol for friendly Rakoons. ) "there isn't any way to directly access the attributes of a Raku object from outside of the object" There's a pound (lb) of wisdom in saying so, and in saying "Pay no attention to that man behind the curtain!", but the 1st of my 2 ounces (oz) is `.^attributes`. "the final `()` forces Raku to treat the interpolated value of `"$_"` as a `Callable`" My 2nd oz is that that's arguably misleading. There may be no such method, just as is so with ordinary method calls. In contrast, `.^methods` *does* return `Callable` objects.